# jQuery UI drag and drop functionality issue in IE

Tags: jquery-ui

I am working on a web app that utilizes jquery UI for drag/drop functionality.

There's a strange problem in IE browsers only. When user drops an item inside a container, that item is added to the container but also leaves a remnant of it on the page.

Here's a working [DEMO](http://www.6ft.me/uxvnbRC).

1. Drag items from the left column to yellow field to create container.
2. Add second item to newly created container.

What's causing it and how can I fix it?

Comment: I hope someone else is willing to wade through all that...

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss I am mostly hoping for someone that encountered similar issue and can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

This happens in IE8 and below.

The error is:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'options': object is
>   null or undefined  jquery-ui.min.js, line 105 character 158

That line is:

```
var a=d(this).data("draggable").options;
```

The jQuery UI version they are using is 1.8.11.

I would suggest upgrading to the [latest version](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#jQuery_UI_Releases_on_the_CDN_1) of jQuery UI and see if that resolves your issue.

If not, you might want to create a test case and [submit it to them as a bug](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/newticket).

Comment: Sure, no problem!  BTW ... I found that simply by using IE's Developer Tools and clicking Start Debugging on the script in question.  It immediately breaks on whatever line throws the error so that you can check it out.